# Mathematical notation library

Tags: soft-question, notation

Do you know some sort of mathematical notation library? Notation reference manual? A list of expressions?

Example:

$\overline{1,n}$. I suppose to understand what that mean, but would be glad to find a list where the context of this notation will be explained. Maybe, referring to authors who use it, or dates when / counrties where this notation was/is used.

Thanks.

Comment: Many books have indices of notation at the back, where you can look this sort of stuff up. That notation is not standard, at least where I'm from.

Comment: @Joppy Some times it's in the front. Some times it's not there at all. It depends.

Comment: usually if there is some weird notation they explain in the exercise. without the comma I would say that it means a two digit number which has first digit $1$ and the second digit is $n$ (counted from left to right).

Comment: in the context I was reading it it was $(1,2,...,n)$. Books are perfect, but the internet consists of not only  books. You can "wikipate" something about Jacobian interation, and many articles will not explain all of the used notation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org) links may be helpful:

- [List of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)
- [Mathematical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_notation)
- [List of mathematical symbols by subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject)
- [History of mathematical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_mathematical_notation)

Comment: for this question it was helpful, thank you!